# ActionBarCompat and Using Navigation Tabs With Fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using the ActionBarCompat project to allow for backwards compatability with the `ActionBar`. Before anyone says about `ActionBarSherlock` I decided to use this because its provided by Google and I don't want to rely on an outside created library. However, if someone can say that any new software updates will be supported by `ActionBarSherlock` then I may be swayed.

I must also add that using the latest `CompatibilitySupport Library` is a must so if I can't do that then I can't use `ActionBarSherlock`

**My Problem**

I have implemented my action bar using the `ActionBarCompat` library and it works on all API's.

I now need to add Tabbed navigation to allow the switching between `Fragments`

**My Question**

Is this easy to implement or do I have to add handling for this myself?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more hunting around for an answer, I found out that its not supported in the `ActionBarCompat`.

I'm going to look into `ActionBarSherlock`. The only thing holding me back is whether or not I can incorporate the `SupportMapFragment` in it.